# How to find closest checkbox if the two checkbox are in different hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two checkbox in different hierarchy. I want to display a text when either one of the checkbox is checked. Hide text when both are unchecked. Both check box have an onClick function  where i am passing "this". How can I find whether second checkbox is checked or not on click of first checkbox.

Note : Id is created dynamically so cannot use that. Below I have mentioned the depth of checkbox (firstCheckbox and SecondCheckbox). What should I write in showMsg(this,Var1) javascript method so that the expectation is met, i.e on click of one of the checkbox, another/closest checkbox is retrieved and its value (checked/unchecked) is available.

```
<f:subview id="firstsubview">
    <f:subview id="secondSubview">
        <f:verbatim>
            <div id="first" class="firstClass">
        </f:verbatim>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="dynamic1" onclick="showMsg(this,'firstcheckbox')" ;/>
        <f:verbatim>
            </div>
        </f:verbatim>
        <h:outputText value="XYZ" id="abc" />
        <f:verbatim>
            <div id="anotherdiv1" class="anotherdiv1" /></div>
            <div id="anotherdiv2" class="anotherdiv2" /></div>
        </f:verbatim>
    </f:subview>
</f:subview>

<f:subview id="thirdsubview">
    <f:subview id="fourthSubview">
        <f:verbatim>
            <div id="second" class="secondclass">
        </f:verbatim>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="dynamic2" onclick="showMsg(this,'secondcheckbox')" ; />
        <f:verbatim>
            </div>
        </f:verbatim>
        <h:outputText value="def" id="ghi" />
        <f:verbatim>
            <div id="anotherdiv3" class="anotherdiv3" /></div>
            <div id="anotherdiv4" class="anotherdiv4" /></div>
        </f:verbatim>
    </f:subview>
</f:subview>

<div id="displayDiv"> This should be displayed if 
any one checkbox or both are check, hidden when both 
checkbox are unchecked</div>
```

Javascript method :

```
function showMsg(checkbox, var1){
if(checkbox.checked){
    $(".displayDiv").show();
} else {
    if(var1 == "firstCheckbox"){
        var nearestCheckbox = $(checkbox).siblings();
        if(nearestCheckbox .checked){
                $(".displayDiv").show();
        } else { $(".displayDiv").hide();}
    //the above code is not working
    }
    if(var1 == "secondCheckbox"){
       //plz suggest what should i write as none is working
    }       
}}
```

Here is Browser generated HTML :

```
<span id="rfmhiddenouterid"><input name="rfmhidden" class="RFM910400060" value="false" <="" span="" type="hidden">
    <div id="first" class="firstClass">
    <input checked="checked" id="AGVUQ0C768TCA0IVC9FC5A2007:dynamic" name="AGVUQ0C768TCA0IVC9FC5A2007: dynamic" class="dynamic111557543" onclick="showMsg(this,'firstcheckbox')" type="checkbox"></div>

    <span id="AGVUQ0C768TCA0IVC9FC5A2007:dynamic"> First CheckBox </span><br><br>             

    <div id="anotherdiv1" class="anotherdiv1" style="display: none;">
    </div>

    <div id="anotherdiv2" class="anotherdiv2" style="display: none;">
    </div>

<span id="rfmhiddenouterid2"><input name="rfmhidden" class="RFM910400060" value="false" <="" span="" type="hidden">
    <div id="second" class="secondClass">
    <input checked="checked" id="AGVUQ0C768TCA0IVC9FC5A2007:dynamic" name="viewns_7_AGVUQ0C768TCA0IVC9FC5A2007:dynamic" class="dynamic111557543" onclick="showMsg(this,'secondcheckbox')"  type="checkbox"></div>

    <span id="viewns_7_AGVUQ0C768TCA0IVC9FC5A2007: dynamic" ">Second Checkbox</span>

    <div id="anotherdiv3" class="anotherdiv3" style="display: none;">
    </div>

    <div id="anotherdiv4" class="anotherdiv4" style="display: none;">
    </div>

    <div id="displayDiv"> This should be displayed if 
    any one checkbox or both are check, hidden when both 
    checkbox are unchecked</div>

</span>
</span>
```

Comment: `if(nearestCheckbox.is(":checked"))` as `nearestCheckbox` is jQuery object.

Comment: I am not able to find nearestCheckbox as it lies in different hierarchy

Comment: I am not familiar with syntax like `f:subview` it struts so I can't help. Can you share generate HTML?

Comment: Syntax error: your <h:selectBooleanCheckbox have both semicolon outside of the onclick value

Comment: Please ignore the syntax issue as i have modified it to make it simple. It would be helpful if you can provide the javascript code that is required.

Comment: Please show your rendered html; JavaScript doesn't work with your script, it works with the HTML your browser receives.

Comment: I have added Browser generated HTML , request you to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with a working solution https://jsfiddle.net/a72t14j0/

Sadly, I have painfully cleaned your HTML but could not debug your code, here is the JavaScript I came up with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".dynamic111557543").on("click", function(){
        // by default, hide the text
        $("#displayDiv").hide();
        var number_of_selected_checkboxes = $(".dynamic111557543:checked").length;
        if(number_of_selected_checkboxes > 0){
            // if any checkbox is checked, show the text
            $("#displayDiv").show();
        }
    });
});
```